# Mysql: Update domain_name field in mailbox table with domain name from domain table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two simple tables:

mailbox_list:

```
+---------+-----------+
| mailbox | domain_id |
+---------+-----------+
```

and
domain_list:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | domain_name |
+----+-------------+
```

I'd like to add another column in mailbox_list filled with domain name (not id), like this

```
+---------+-----------+-------------+
| mailbox | domain_id | domain_name |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

Yes I can SELECT that but not sure how to UPDATE new column in one query. Looks like this is simple operation, but miss the idea.

Please advice!

Answer (score 0):

Denormalising a Table is a **bad idea** as the information is redundant and you need to update all domain names once they change and else you need to change only the domain list , and indexes on id and domain_id would amke all queries quite fast

That said

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mailbox_list (mailbox varchar(10), domain_id int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mailbox_list VALUES('test',1)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE domain_list ( id int, domain_name varchar(10))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO domain_list VALUES (1,'mydom')
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE mailbox_list ADD COLUMN domain_name varchar(10)
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE mailbox_list m
> JOIN domain_list d ON d.id = m.domain_id
> SET m.domain_name = d.domain_name
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM mailbox_list
> ```
>
> ```
> mailbox | domain_id | domain_name
> :------ | --------: | :----------
> test    |         1 | mydom
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3a75d11442b78b86a31019f3fbd46a8a)*